# How can I express $x^2+y^2=1$ as an explicit function?

Tags: functions, circles

In his book, *Differential Equations Demystified*, Steven G. Krantz writes that the unit circle can be expressed: 
$$y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ when $y$ is positive and $$y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$  when $y$ is negative. He adds: "It is only at the exceptional points $(-1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ where the tangent lines are vertical that $y$ *cannot* be expressed as a function of $x$."

First off, let me say that I think he means to identify those points as $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$, but even allowing for the typo, I'm still a wee bit mystified.

Either of those two points represents a solution to *both*  equations. Is it that there is the equations give the same value for $y$ at $x=0$? What is his point here?

Comment: I would totally agree with him if you replaced the word "cannot" by "can" ( and fixed the other typo)

Comment: Augh! Typos in math books!

Comment: His point is that he cannot represent $y$ as a function of $x$ in a neighbourhood of those points.

Comment: I don't understand that. Could you please explain it?

Comment: He is alluding informally to the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: @AdamHrankowski I upvoted and favorited your question, so if nobody answers by tomorrow and/or you have not understood, I'll try to clear things up. I must sleep now, so I can't do it right now... sorry.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo - I see the connection with the Implicit Function Theorem in the linked articles and in another place with MSE... but the 'aha' evades me. What I see about these functions is that they overlap at these points. I think I need to review what "neighbourhood" means in this context.

Comment: @WW1 *where the tangent lines are vertical that* y *cannot be expressed as a function of* x. I think he is saying that the **tangents** are not functions at those points (as they are vertical lines, there are infinite values of *y* for *x* = 1) - and not that the **circle equation** is not a function because it has more than one value at those points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following picture:

[image]

If we look near enough of $x$, it is clear that this picture represents a function: we have associated to every $x$ a unique $y$. For instance:

[image]

But if we slide $x$ to the right part, this does not hold anymore: we have $2$ values associated to $x$, no matter what neighbourhood of $x$ we choose:

[image]

But if we also restrict ourselves on a neighbourhood of one of those values associated to $x$, we can arrive at $y$ as a function of $x$. For example:

[image]

However, if $x$ is at the far right, there will be no way to do this, no matter what neighbourhood of $y$ and $x$ you take! See the following picture:

[image]

This occurs due to the fact that the picture is "vertical" at the far right. This issue is adressed formally by the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: Thanks so much. This really helps. Would it be true for anywhere that the tangent is zero? Do we say in your example that Y cannot be expressed as a function of x in the neighbourhood of that point?

Comment: @AdamHrankowski It is true for every point in which the tangent line is not vertical (assuming that the function is differentiable and with continuous derivative). This can be intuitively explained by saying that a "well-behaved function (namely, a function which is differentiable with continuous derivative) behaves locally in a very similar way to its tangent line".

Comment: With respect to your second question, the right thing to say is that y cannot be expressed as a function of x in a neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ (that is, of the pair of points in the plane). We are interested in a neighbourhood because of the fact that derivation is an operation that is very well behaved in open sets. If we didn't require **open** neighbourhoods, we could say that $y$ could be expressed as a function of $x$ (just take the interval $[y,\infty)$). But openness is something we don't want to sacrifice.